# How to concatenate three pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have three pandas dataframes: df1, df2, df3 which looks like as follows:

df1=

| X | Y | M1_x | M2_x | M3_x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 33 | 3 | 4 | 2 |
| 12 | 54 | 0 | 3 | 4 |
| 23 | 12 | 0 | 8 | 3 |

df2=

| X | Y | M1_y | M2_y | M3_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 33 | 9 | 4 | 1 |
| 12 | 54 | 0 | 3 | 5 |
| 12 | 11 | 0 | 2 | 1 |

df3=

| X | Y | M1_z | M2_z | M3_z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 33 | 1 | 40 | 10 |
| 11 | 10 | 10 | 30 | 0 |
| 12 | 11 | 0 | 40 | 5 |

I like to concatenate the two df and get the merged dataframe as below:

result =

| X | Y | M1_x | M2_x | M3_x | M1_y | M2_y | M3_y | M1_z | M2_z | M3_z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 33 | 3 | 4 | 2 | 9 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 40 | 10 |
| 12 | 54 | 0 | 3 | 4 | 0 | 3 | 5 | nan | nan | nan |
| 23 | 12 | 0 | 8 | 3 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 12 | 11 | nan | nan | nan | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 40 | 5 |
| 11 | 10 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 10 | 30 | 0 |

I already tried p.cocatenate function, the problem is choosing axis=1, doesn't merge the[X, Y] columns, then I have double [X,Y] columns in the result file, choosing axis=0, doesn't merge the rows, and I get the union of rows instead of merging common [X,Y] with eachother.
How can I make this happen?

**EDIT:**
I know how to use merge function when merging two dataframes. My problem here is I have more than two (actually 4) databases to merge. Is there any function to combine more than two dfs in one line?

Comment: changed wrong dupe to correct.

Comment: In dupe is also solution for processing multiple DataFrames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) specifying how to merge (outer merge):

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, 'outer').merge(df3, 'outer')
   X   Y   M1_x   M2_x   M3_x  M1_y   M2_y   M3_y  M1_z   M2_z   M3_z
0  12  33    3.0    4.0   2.0    9.0    4.0   1.0    1.0   40.0  10.0
1  12  54    0.0    3.0   4.0    0.0    3.0   5.0    NaN    NaN   NaN
2  23  12    0.0    8.0   3.0    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN
3  12  11    NaN    NaN   NaN    0.0    2.0   1.0    0.0   40.0   5.0
4  11  10    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN   10.0   30.0   0.0
```

---

If you have more dataframes you can do something like this:

```
out = df1.copy()
dfs = [df2,df3,df4,df5,df6]
for df in dfs:
    out = out.merge(df, 'outer')
```

---

This diagram clarifies the different types of merge (`pandas` uses inner merge as default):
[image: Types of merge]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well, I wanted to summerize my question and reduce the number of dfs to two. My real problem is dealing with 4 dfs. Is it still possible to use your solution?

Comment: @maedenasri of course, you only need to "chain" merges or looping through a list of yours dataframes while merging :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if this can help.

```
new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2,  how='outer')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: this doesn't give the desired result in the question by the way.

Comment: change `how` parameter from `left` to `outer`...It will work